# How to add a Drawable to WebView

Tags: java, android

Json

```
 {
   "text": "  «Le président du Bloc du Changement et de la Réforme",
   "imagepath": "http://www.example.com/dori%20chamoun-saidaonline.jpg"
  }
```

I get the text and fetch image from url as drawable

```
 introtext = jArray.getString("introtext");
```

and

```
 InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
 Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
```

My problem is, i want to display both the image and text in same WebView.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in Drawable. You can use `loadData` method of WebView. For example:

```
String content="<html><body><img src=\""+image_path+"\" /><br/>"+your_text+"</body></html>";
wview.loadData(content,"text/html",null);
```

where `wview` is your WebView, `image_path` is image path and `your_text` is your text (there is no surprises here)

Comment: Thanks man.. i've been trying to find this for like 2 days now